# Кроссбраузерный перенос сплошного текста.

Tags: text, html, php, css

Здравствуйте.
Знаете ли вы какой-нибудь кроссбраузерный способ переноса сплошного текста. Так, например, свойство `word-wrap` есть CSS3 свойство, и поэтому оно работает далеко не во всех браузерах( хоть и почти во всех современных ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось написать свою функцию разбива сплошного текста пробелами:

```
 function splitter($str, $pos=0)
{
    $found = false;
    for($i = $pos; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        if($str[$i] == " ") $found=true;
        if($i != 0)
        if(( $i % 45 ) == 0)
        {
            if($found == false)
            {
              $s1=mb_substr($str,0,$i);
              $s2=mb_substr($str,$i,mb_strlen($str)-$i+1);
              $str = $s1."<br>".$s2;
            }

            }

        }
    return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Решили вставлять пробелы где попало, может лучше символ мягкого переноса (&shy;)?

Answer (score 2):

Ну попробуй так:

```
pre, code 
      { white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
        white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */ 
        word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ твой случай*/ }
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло...